# Update all documents matching a list entry and create new documents for list entries without matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

#### The problem

I have a MongoDB collection of `Session` documents with three fields: a `user`, a `fromTimestamp` and a `toTimestamp`. In my code, I have a list of `user`s whose `toTimestamp`s I need to update to now.

For every `user` on my list:

- If there is an existing `Session` with the `toTimestamp` being no further than 1 minute ago, I want it updated to now.
- If there isn't one, I want to create a new `Session`, with both `fromTimestamps` and `toTimestamp` being set to now.

Can I achieve this with one or two queries, in an efficient way?

#### Current solution

What I am currently doing, is using `findMany` to find all matching existing `Session`s, getting their ID's and `user`s. Then a bulk write with `updateMany` updates all the sessions with the collected ID's. A list of users gets created that were not returned from the initial query - these are the users that didn't have matching `Session`s. For these, another bulk write inserts new `Session`s.

However, this is 3 queries, and requires looping through all `users` to find which ones didn't have a matching `Session`. There might be thousands of `user`s and I'm looking for a solution that will solve this efficiently, hopefully with a single query, without needing to compute differences in local code.

#### Sample data

Suppose the database contains these values:

`Session(user: Alice, fromTimestamp: 0, toTimestamp: 10)`

`Session(user: Bob, fromTimestamp: 5, toTimestamp: 15)`

`Session(user: Claire: fromTimestamp: 0, toTimestamp: 20)`

The timestamp now is 25.
We get an update list of: `Alice, Claire, Dan`. Looking for sessions up to 10 ago, concerning these users, we find just `Claire`. `Dan` doesn't have a session already, `Alice` does, but it's `toTimestamp` is more than 10 ago. So there is only one session to update: `Claire`. It's `toTimestamp` is set to now, which is 25. That leaves `Alice` and `Dan`, for which we create new sessions. The resulting database is:

`Session(user: Alice, fromTimestamp: 0, toTimestamp: 10)`

`Session(user: Bob, fromTimestamp: 5, toTimestamp: 15)`

`Session(user: Claire: fromTimestamp: 0, toTimestamp: 25)`

`Session(user: Alice: fromTimestamp: 25, toTimestamp: 25)`

`Session(user: Dan: fromTimestamp: 25, toTimestamp: 25)`

For users with recent sessions, the sessions are extended. For users with no recent sessions, new sessions are created.

Comment: I am not getting your first point  `If there is an existing Session with the toTimestamp being no further than 1 minute ago, I want it updated to now.` means if toTimestamp < 1 min then update otherwise add,  it will helpful to add sample data and your tried queries in your question.

Comment: @turivishal I have updated the question with example input and output data.

Comment: @Nohus could you add a bit more examples? I mean MongoPlayground will be pretty fine, cause I still don't understand what exactly you wanted to achieve. I mean, I understand that you are trying to do, but I don't see the logic of the code, to give a relevant answer/advice.

Comment: @AlexZeDim I have a collection of user sessions, with timestamps where they started and ended (or were seen last). I get a list of users that are online right now. For those online users that have a recent session, I now see they are still online, so I update the recent session - it hasn't actually ended a minute ago because I see they are still online, and the `toTimestamp` should point to now, because now is the most recent time they were seen. For users without a recent session I want to create new sessions.

Comment: @Nohus, so this: *for users without a recent session I want to create new sessions* is why you are using `updateMany` with `upsert: true` option? Am I correct? And you don't to iterate user over user for it, you want to updateAll (many of them) via one query. Right?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can't use `upsert: true`. It would only create one document when no documents matching documents for the update are found. It won't create new documents for all users without a recent session.

Comment: I want to update all matching recent sessions, and create all the sessions that don't have a recent match, in one query if possible, without having to iterate over all users in my code.